# Mongodb Match or Like Query

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have list of documents in mongodb like

```
{
        "id": "5948b044ef91edb15d222794",
        "articleId": "4",
        "author": "asdfghjkl",
        "publicationDate": 1454371200000,
        "rating": 4,
        "numViews": 600000,
        "summary": "In the end, bombastic bozo Donald Trump’s predictions of an Iowa victory were all a big, sad joke.",
        "articleUrl": "http://www.asdfghjkl.com/news/politics/donald-trump-predicts-iowa-victory-voters-caucusing-article-1.2516776",
        "keywords": [
            "Trump",
            "Election"
        ],
        "imgPath": [
            "http://assets.asdfghjkl.com/polopoly_fs/1.2516971.1454384425!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_1200/usa-election-trump.jpg"
        ],
        "articleName": "Ted Cruz, after trailing in polls, beats Donald Trump in Iowa caucus; Marco Rubio finishes a close third"
    }
```

I have a list of keywords (Strings like ["Trump","Donald","Election"]) which i want to match with the `keywords` and `articleName` columns in these documents.

so, How can i get matched documents from collection using `$in or $or or regex` in java spring-boot??

Comment: By using spring data! Please show some effort on your part if you want people to help you.

Comment: Put your `@Repository` in the question and the interface that implements with this information we could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

Query query = new Query();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Trump", "Election");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("keywords").in(list));
List<YourModel> yourModel = mongoTemplate.find(query, YourModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have did this by following implementation using $regex :

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ keywords: { $regex: '(?:[\\s]|^)("+keywords+")(?=[\\s]|$)',$options: 'i' } } ");
  articlesList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Articles.class);
```

where keywords are like : keyword1|keyword2|keyword3